# error: X was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

In my method for Bank.cpp, this is what I wrote:

```
string printaccount(int loc) {
ostringstream output;

double integer;
integer = list[loc]->getintbal() * (_intrate/12) * _months + list[loc]->getcurrbal();

etc etc;
}
```

But my code keeps telling me list, _intrate and _months was not declared.

I checked my Bank.h file but everything seems ok/have been declared properly.

```
class Bank{
private:
double _intrate;
int _months;
vector <Account*> list;

etc etc;
}
```

Can't seem to debug this one...

Comment: Is `printaccount` a member of `Bank`?

Answer (score 2):

Is `printaccount` part of the `Bank` class?

```
string Bank::printaccount(int log) {...}
```